# How to use ES6 features inside of my nodejs/expressjs app using Gulp or Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, ecmascript-6, webpack

I want to use ES6 features inside of my nodejs/expressjs application. At the moment i am using Gulp to compile my js and setup other stuff like live reload.

1. What do i need to add to my existing gulp file in order to compile the es6 code to standard js.
2. I see webpack used a lot how can i do everything im doing with gulp using webpack instead.

```

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('default', function() {

    livereload.listen();

    nodemon({

        script: 'index.js',
        ext: 'js'

    }).on('restart', function() {

        gulp.src('index.js')
            .pipe(livereload())
            .pipe(notify('Reloading page, please wait...'));
    });

});
```

```

thank you.

Comment: why not just switch to nodejs v.6.x.x most of old code stays the same, just little fixes

Comment: Can i use imports with that version of nodejs?

Comment: still not. I've doubts that it will not be implemented on nodejs, cuz require, export, module.export  features are too mature

Comment: Gulp and Webpack are oranges and apples. It is possible to implement some of Gulp tasks in Webpack, but in the end Gulp+Webpack chain offers the most flexible workflow, see https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream

Answer (score 0):

In node js 6 you can already use ES6 without compiler or other stuff, just add 'use strict' at the start of your js file.

If you have node < 6, you can use babel to compile your js to ES5 before starting your app.

see this article: http://jsrocks.org/2016/01/configuring-babel-6-for-node-js/

ES6 module is in DRAFT for now so you can't use import/export for now
see https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/blob/master/002-es6-modules.md

Comment: Can i use imports with that version of nodejs

Comment: I think import doesn't work. I saw on Github that they have to do some work to replace require and they don't have time to replace it for now. Just edited my answer with a link to github

Comment: can babel help me use import modules?